# Disable button interaction if below another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, touch

I'd like to disable a button interaction if it is below another view.

On this example, my UIButton is the green frame.
I can tap on it and it will call the right selector (with control event "UIControlEventTouchUpInside"). But this call also work if I tap on the red frame which is above the green button, and I don't want that...

[image: Example screenshot]

Any help to disable the interaction where the button isn't visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting :

```
theUpperView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```